# Partial Convex Hull

Tags: c#, convex-hull

I have a polygon with vertices P1, P2,P3,.....P11. My vertex coordinate data types are double.

[image]

I also have a line between P1, P7.

I want to create a partial convex hull between P1 and P7 and keep my original polygon vertices after P7.

So final polygon will be as follow;

[image]

So far I convert the whole polygon to convex hull, delete vertices in convex hull and add hull vertices. It works fine with small polygons but it won't be easy to manage that way when vertex number increases.

I tried to look for c# algorithms available for partial convex hull but i couldn't find anything except some researches.

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly does the line going through the middle have to do with the problem?

Comment: Just random, not in the middle. That is why Andrew's monotone chain convex hull algorithm doesn't  fit either :(

Comment: But where did it come from and how is it related to the problem?

Comment: Polygon represents the obstacle and line is a direct line extension between start and end points which crosses the obstacle.

Comment: Are you doing the partial convex hull in order to make sure there are no obstacles between those points? Because that wouldn’t always work. On the other hand, there are also many cases in which the partial convex hull defined by the vertices between those two point is much more than you need in order to remove the obstacle. Perhaps more details about what your end goal is would help us help you a little more.

Comment: I am trying to get the shortest path in continuous space with spatial analytic approach. Using partial convex hull will reduce the workload on graph. I am not trying to avoid obstacles between those points. P1&P7 are the intersection points with my direct line(start&end points).

Comment: Pick three sequential vertices. Find the 2d "cross product" (not really defined in 2D but it still works). If the sign of the cross product is negative `(P3-P2) cross (P1-P2)`, delete the middle vertex.

Comment: @3Dave Can you explain more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I clipped the polygon by using DotSpatial

```
internal static IGeometry Polygonize(IGeometry geometry)
        {
            var lines = LineStringExtracter.GetLines(geometry);
            var polygonizer = new Polygonizer();
            polygonizer.Add(lines);
            var polys = polygonizer.GetPolygons();
            var polyArray = GeometryFactory.ToGeometryArray(polys);
            return geometry.Factory.CreateGeometryCollection(polyArray);
        }

        internal static IGeometry PolygonizeForClip(IGeometry geometry, IPreparedGeometry clip)
        {
            var lines = LineStringExtracter.GetLines(geometry);
            var clippedLines = new List<IGeometry>();
            foreach (ILineString line in lines)
            {
                if (clip.Contains(line))
                    clippedLines.Add(line);
            }
            var polygonizer = new Polygonizer();
            polygonizer.Add(clippedLines);
            var polys = polygonizer.GetPolygons();
            var polyArray = GeometryFactory.ToGeometryArray(polys);
            return geometry.Factory.CreateGeometryCollection(polyArray);
        }

        internal static IGeometry SplitPolygon(IGeometry polygon, IGeometry line)
        {
            var nodedLinework = polygon.Boundary.Union(line);
            var polygons = Polygonize(nodedLinework);

            // only keep polygons which are inside the input
            var output = new List<IGeometry>();
            for (var i = 0; i < polygons.NumGeometries; i++)
            {
                var candpoly = (IPolygon)polygons.GetGeometryN(i);
                if (polygon.Contains(candpoly.InteriorPoint))
                    output.Add(candpoly);
            }

            return polygon.Factory.BuildGeometry(output);
        }

        internal static IGeometry ClipPolygon(IGeometry polygon, IPolygonal clipPolygonal)
        {
            var clipPolygon = (IGeometry)clipPolygonal;
            var nodedLinework = polygon.Boundary.Union(clipPolygon.Boundary);
            var polygons = Polygonize(nodedLinework);


            // only keep polygons which are inside the input
            var output = new List<IGeometry>();
            for (var i = 0; i < polygons.NumGeometries; i++)
            {
                var candpoly = (IPolygon)polygons.GetGeometryN(i);
                var interiorPoint = candpoly.InteriorPoint;
                if (polygon.Contains(interiorPoint) &&

                    clipPolygon.Contains(interiorPoint))
                    output.Add(candpoly);
            }

            return polygon.Factory.BuildGeometry(output);
        }
```

then

```
var Splitted = SplitPolygon(Polygon, Line);
```

Then added parts.

Answer (score 0):

Remove vertices P8 through P11 from your polygon and store them off, then run the convex hull conversion on what's left (P1 through P7). After, re-insert vertices P8 through P11 (between P7 and P1).

Comment: That is what I am doing now, but I need a better solution. I am planning on working with polygons which have 1M vertices and it won't be a proper approach.

Comment: Apologies if I'm misunderstanding, but it sounds like what you're doing now is running a conversion over the whole polygon, which can be optimized if you first remove the vertices you want to leave alone. If that's already the case, what gains do you imagine from a different approach?

If you're going to convert a high percentage of the 1M vertices, then I'm not sure what more can be done than finding a performant hull conversion algorithm. If you expect to convert a low percentage, then the described method should be sufficient.

Are there more specific bottlenecks that concern you?

Comment: actually whole polygon takes about 3ms for converting to convex hull with dotspatial. Deleting and reconstructing takes longer especially with large polygons. I was just tired of delete and reconstruct so thought maybe there is something out there to make this easier. I am working on other approach by clipping the polygon into pieces using dotspatial, apply convex hull the pieces i need to and union the pieces again. looks like it takes less than my first approach.